# C compound assignment operator ^= mean

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

I did not understand the `^` operator used in this code. Please help me.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;

    cin >> n;

    vector<int> a(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     int ans = a[i]^1;
     cout<<" ans "<<ans<<"  ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `^` operator is the bitwise XOR operator. Given two numbers a, b, [which are internally represented by bits], a ^ b contains 1-bits at spots where only one of the numbers a, b, contains the 1-bit at that spot.

Comment: `^` is bitwise XOR (exclusive or).    `a ^= b` has same net effect as `a = a ^ b`.

Answer (score 0):

it's XOR operator (exclusive OR op.):
will toggle (invert) the bit of an operand in position where any bit having value 1 in the other operand

```
 int ans = a[i]^1;
```

e.g. a 4 byte size, at an i:

```
a[i] = 00000000 0000000 1000000 1000001

  1  = 00000000 0000000 0000000 0000001 
      ---------------------------------- XOR
       00000000 0000000 1000000 1000000
                                      ^ --> 1st bit of a[i] get toggled
```